# Qt 5.1 application doesnt work on Windows 8 outside QtCreator, Runtime Error

Tags: c++, qt, runtime-error

I wrote a very simple application in Qt 5.1/C++. I wrote it on Windows 7 64 bit. I took *.exe file builded by QtCreator, pasted it in a newly created folder, and added some *.dlls there.

So the content of my folder looks like this:

```
myapp.exe
icudt51.dll
icuin51.dll
icuuc51.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
```

and it all works on my computer. However, I send it to my friend to test it on his Windws 8 64 bit, and he got such error:

[image]

What else should I do to make it possible that my friend on Windows 8 can run my application?

On my computer dependecy walker says, that I need those dlls:

[image]

Unfortunately, still doesnt work, on Windows XP too:

[image]
[image]

Ok, finally worked!

[image]

qwindows.dll needs to be in directory called platforms.

Comment: Have you checked whether your application loads the correct dll's over at you friend's machine? I had this error with my application loading system32-installed dlls instead of the ones I provided. Very nasty and hard to debug.

Comment: @arne: how can I check it?

Comment: I think it was this one: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: @arne: huh, my friend installed (this)[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679], I also added to the folder a file `msvcr100.dll` and same issue occured, on my Windows XP too. What now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create folder `<your-app-dir>/platforms` and copy in files qwindows.dll, qminimal.dll, and maybe also libEGL.dll.

See documentation here:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html (Search for qwindows.dll)

Also:

- http://forum.qt.io/topic/24553/this-application-has-requested-the-runtime-to-terminate-it-in-an-unusual-way

Comment: Where is the libEGL.dll? I never found that :\

Comment: Per the docs in the first link above: `If you are using ANGLE (the default) then you additionally need to include both libEGL.dll and libGLESv2.dll from Qt's 'lib' directory as well as the HLSL compiler from DirectX. The HLSL compiler library is called d3dcompiler_XX.dll where XX is the version number that ANGLE (libGLESv2) was linked against.`